# Can't get audio from center channel and subwoofer in 5.1 setup

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm on Kubuntu 19.10 and I'm trying to configure Creative X-Fi XtremeGamer audio card with my 5.1 speakers with no success. I can't get the output for center channel and subwoofer. Here are some screenshots of the audio config panels. I can provide more if needed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5r12.jpg

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I've just found out what was happening. For anyone with the same issue, just run `alsamixer` from the Terminal and press F6 to make sure your sound card is selected. Then look for volume controls marked with "MM" instead of "00" at the bottom of the green bar [in my case: Center/LFE]. These are muted channels, so you need to select them using arrow keys and press "M" to unmute. Press "Esc" and you're good to go. As simple as that.

Now why Alsa Mixer overrides every other settings - like PulseAudio Control and system settings - and these channels are muted by default is beyond my comprehension